# Max rows in SQL table where PK is INT 32 when seed starts at max negative value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is the maximum number of rows in an SQL server table where the Primary Key Identity is INT 32 type:

> 4,294,967,294
>
> i.e  2,147,483,647 positive numbers add 2,147,483,647 negative numbers

The reason I ask is a system was destined to use all 2,147,483,647 numbers.

Reset the seed to negative -2,147,483,647 months ago successfully.

Also implemented an Agent task to remove unused positive numbers.

Table count check of PK ID each day reports the number of rows in the table is tantalisingly close to 2,147,483,647 but has not breached to date.

> Sat 28         /   2,125,167,844
>
> Fri 27         /   2,128,445,105
>
> Thur 26        /       2,128,704,866
>
> Wed 25          /   2,128,935,436
>
> Sat 21         /   2,141,016,422
>
> Thur 19        /       2,143,413,531

In theory this row count should reach 4,294,967,294 if all positive and negative identities where in use correct ?

Find it odd that this count has never been greater than the max positive value. The query below is a simple row count, +/- identities should not matter.

> select COUNT (id) from table with (NOLOCK)

Thanks

Comment: Max number of rows per table is "Limited by available storage", so it can be more than 4G. Max file size (data) 16TB. Database size 524,272 terabytes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx You can also convert your `int` `IDENTITY` to `bigint` if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can go all the way up to identity 0 again and you could go up to holding 4,294,967,294 records in your table. However you say you're "removing unused positive numbers" if this process always deletes the oldest records first then it should give much troubles. If you're deleting random data don't expect those numbers to be automatically be used by identity. When inserting into an identity column SQL Server remembers the last inserted identity and increments it by 1 and then does the insert, if the number exists, it will give a key violation error if there is a unique key on that column.

PS: There are faster ways to count all rows in a table:

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Transactions')   
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

PS2: Makes sure to put the result of an count in a bigint ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Removing oldest positives first from zero upwards. Have tested INSERT row from minus ID to positive ID successfully, this is not the concern. My concern was every count to date appeared to be less than the max positive int, from your reply it appears this concern has no foundation. The delete row routine simple must be keeping it below 2,147,483,647.