# Batch stored procedure with transactions and table variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data migration this weekend and come to find out I wont be able to get a DBA's help so my SQL Server knowledge is lacking.  All of the other DBA's are Oracle and wont touch SQL Server.  I'm limited on security, and I can't create a job or SSIS package to handle this.

I have a script in which I'm running as a batch.  Within this batch, I am running a stored procedure with the logic.  The stored procedure has table variables, and I just read that you're unable to run these as a transaction.  Can someone eyeball this overall approach and see if I'm missing anything or I can run it more efficiently?  The BigTable has approximately 25M records and all indexes, FKs, contraints are dropped.  I plan on temporarily adding a few indexes for this batch.  It will run around 5 days.

```
Create Procedure ConvertStuff AS
BEGIN

declare @id uniqueIdentifier
declare @importdate DateTime
declare @Data varchar(max)

declare @tableX table 
    ---
declare @tableY table 
    ---
declare @tableZ table 
    ---


SET NOCOUNT ON
    select top 1 @ID = bt.ID, @Data = bt.RawData, @importDate = bt.ImportDate from Processed p with (NOLOCK)
        Inner join BigTable bt with (NOLOCK) on p.ID = bt.ID where p.isProcessed = 0

    while (not @ID is null)
    Begin
        BEGIN TRY
            --Do stuff here
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

            DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
            DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
            DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

            SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
                   @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
                   @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

            RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,
                       @ErrorSeverity,
                       @ErrorState
                       );


            update bigTable set isProcessed = -1 where ID = @ID
            break
        END CATCH
    select top 1 @ID = bt.ID, @Data = bt.RawData, @importDate = bt.ImportDate from Processed p with (NOLOCK)
        Inner join BigTable bt with (NOLOCK) on p.ID = bt.ID where p.isProcessed = 0
    END
    --Do I need to drop the @ tables here? Should I convert these to # ?
END

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Running this....

-- This will be dropped once the migration is done
CREATE TABLE [Processed]
(
    [ID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [isProcessed] [bit] Default(0) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_isProcessed] ON [Processed]
(
    [isProcessed] ASC
)

GO

SET ROWCOUNT 25000

declare @msg varchar(50)
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
DECLARE @ErrorState INT

While (1=1) 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    Insert into [Processed] (ID, isProcessed) 
        Select ID, 0 from BigTable where recordUpdated = 0

    exec ConvertStuff

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        Print @@ROWCOUNT
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        BREAK
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION


        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
               @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
               @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();
        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );
        BREAK
    END CATCH
END

drop table Processed
```

Comment: There are a number of issues here. First I don't see any reason you need to be using a loop. Second is you have thrown the NOLOCK hint on every single table. Last but not least is you have a top with no order by.

Comment: The reason for the loop is so I can do this as a batch and flag each data element that fails.  The other is that the inner logic goes through TSQL logic that I didn't put, and isn't relevent to the post.  The nolocks I can take out.  The app will be down anyway.  I'll add the order by, I'm assuming this should be indexed as well for bigTable?

Comment: Indexing that may or may not help honestly. You also will need to update each row in BigTable as you process it which I don't see here either. I can sort of understand a loop here but I strongly dislike loops that are while 1 = 1.

Comment: Perhaps this is the case where a cursor is more appropriate than searching for the next row to process each time through the loop, unless you really want to pick up new data as you march along. `not @ID is null` is typically written `@ID is not null`.

Comment: The BigTable update is done within the logic I commented out, same with processed table.  Is there a faster, easier way than the while 1=1?  HABO - I removed all the cursors since at that time, I was going to run this script all at once.  But due to random issues, I'm taking the step back and doing this as a batch so I can address any issues that pop up when this is running.  Thank you everyone for the info, this is awesome to learn.

Comment: I agree with @Habo. A cursor would likely be a better option here. I am just concerned that your are doing this on 25M rows. No matter which way you go about this if you stick with RBAR processing it is going to take a LONG time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper way to efficiently bulk copy a table without killing your system.  This strategy only works if the table is read-only during the copy.  If your table can change you'll have to pair this with another strategy for tracking and updating changed records.

The batch copy approach will prevent you from holding a 4 day lock on the table and will allow you to continue backing up your transaction logs at regular intervals.  It also will prevent a 4 day rollback in the event you either need to stop it or it fails.

Run this before your release, then again during the release to cap of the table.  As always, practice running and stopping your script before trying on a live system.

```
DECLARE @CurrentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @BatchSize INT;
SET @BatchSize = 50000;

SELECT TOP 1
    @CurrentId = ID
FROM NewTable
ORDER BY ID DESC;

SELECT
    @LastId = ID
FROM OldTable
ORDER BY ID DESC;

IF (@CurrentId IS NULL)
    SET @CurrentId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000';

PRINT 'Copying from ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), @CurrentId) + ' to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), @LastId);

CREATE TABLE #Batch
(
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
);

WHILE (@CurrentId < @LastId)
BEGIN
    PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), @CurrentId);

    TRUNCATE TABLE #Batch;

    -- Get your new batch
    INSERT INTO #Batch
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize)
        *
    FROM OldTable
    WHERE ID > @CurrentId
    ORDER BY ID;

    -- I'd recommend being specific with columns, you might also need to turn on 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT <Table> ON'
    INSERT INTO NewTable
    SELECT *
    FROM OldTable
    INNER JOIN #Batch ON #Batch.ID = OldTable.ID
    LEFT JOIN NewTable ON NewTable.ID = OldTable.ID
    WHERE NewTable.ID IS NULL;

    IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
        BREAK

    SELECT TOP 1
        @CurrentId = ID
    FROM #Batch
    ORDER BY ID DESC;
END
```

Comment: Sorry, in that case a slight adjustment is needed.

Comment: The identity seed can be reset, e.g. to a large negative value. That makes the use of MIN and MAX problematic. [`IDENT_CURRENT()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) may help determine where new rows are being added, but it can still get confusing especially if reseeding is a popular pastime.

Comment: Methinks a point @dave2118 was making is that `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` values are not guaranteed to be issued in any particular order. That makes them about as fun as pseudorandomly reseeding integers that are sufficiently well behaved to not repeat.

Comment: They were pointing out that my initial script used MIN(INT) and MAX(INT) to find the boundaries that needed copied.  If you have a solution for any identity seed problems I'd like to see it.  In my experience SQL server has always adjusted itself automatically.  My solution has numerous enhancements, not to mention I've personally used it on a 4 billion record table.

Comment: I don't have any workarounds for reseeding, just happened to recall seeing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28779852/max-rows-in-sql-table-where-pk-is-int-32-when-seed-starts-at-max-negative-value) post recently and realized it would be an issue.